# Microsoft Edge sandboxing of external Javascript code breaks Prototype

Tags: javascript, security, prototypejs, sandbox, microsoft-edge

What Microsoft Edge is doing, at least from what I can see, is that any external javascript(ie javascript from any other FQDN that is different from the websites) is being "sandboxed" to an extent.

I'm not sure how much it is being sandboxed, but Edge will not let you see function code. So if you were to do a someFunction.toString(), you will get

```
function someFunction() { [native code] }
```

where as in any other browser you would get

```
function someFunction(args, args1) { /*the functions code*/ }
```

You can of course run the function but you can't print it out. Where this gets to be a problem is with Prototype. For subclasses, prototype does a toString of a function to see if it has "$super" as its first argument. If it does, then it knows to link that with a parent class's function. If prototype can't see a text version of the function, any subclasses will not work correctly.

There are no security settings in Edge that can be changed.

Does anyone know any workaround or do we just have to wait and see if Microsoft will fix this?

!!!UPDATE!!!

I just confirmed that the latest [Windows 10 Cumulative Update](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3081438) has fixed the issue. Thanks!

Comment: I created https://jsbin.com/belete/edit?html which loads jQuery from a cdn and I am able to inspect it's functions without a problem. Could you post a sample somewhere showing the problem?

Comment: So I just tried this with loading jquery on my server and I did see that I can toString a function in it. I am at a lost to why when using PrototypeJS i can not do this.

Comment: Just confirmed that the latest [Windows 10 Cumulative update](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3081438) fixed this issue.